# WCF service timeout

Tags: wcf, timeout

Is there a way to set a tiemout on the service side so that the request stops processing if it exceeds the timeout?  I know I can time the request out on the client side, but that doesn't stop the processing of the request on the server.

I've tried adding the following binding:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="timeout" receiveTimeout="00:01:00" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" />
</basicHttpBinding>
```

I've also tried adding the following in the system.web node (separately and together with the above):

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="60" /> <!-- timeout after 60 seconds -->
```

Comment: The timeouts that you can configure on the Endpoint's binding configuration are mostly linked with transport/channel timeouts, what you are asking for is a way to time-limit your service processing-code regardless of how much communication time is necessary right? for example you would like to set that your WCF service will abort processing operations if it takes more than 2 minutes ... is this what you are asking?

Comment: @Csharpenter - that's basically correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no built in (out of the box) way to do this. All of the timeouts that you can set are related to transport settings. In short words, you have to do that yourself.

Please also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2944969/339204) about limiting WCF execution time.

Comment: Thanks.  May have to wait for a later project, then, since I won't have time to get a custom solution into the current project.

Answer (score 1):

You can set this up in your service bindings, the link below shows the values to set on the service side as well as client side.

http://geekswithblogs.net/smyers/archive/2011/10/05/wcf-service-message-timeouts-size-limits-tips-and-tricks.aspx

Comment: That's a good article, but setting the timeouts on the binding doesn't seem to work.  Neither does setting the httpRuntime executionTimeout.

Answer (score 1):

We can set server side time out in "Binding" with:

```
Binding.ReceiveTimeout
```

This is the timeout that specifies how long the service can wait from the beginning of receiving a request until the message is processed. It’s server-side setting. When you send a large message to the service and the service needs long time to process, you would need to increase this setting.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731361.aspx

Using these two timeouts should solve most timeout problems. However, when a WCF service is hosted in IIS/ASP.NET, another setting would also control the lifetime of the request:

> HttpRuntimeSection.ExecutionTimeout

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
  <httpRuntime executionTimeout="600"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: See my most recent edit - that doesn't seem to limit the time from start to end of the full service call, which is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: AFAIK that is not true. For more information on `ReceiveTimeout` see http://www.rauch.io/2015/06/25/all-wcf-timeouts-explained/

Answer (score 0):

yes i can handle it you have to configure your web.config file it's look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <add name="DomainServiceModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHttpModule, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </modules>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
</system.webServer>

<system.web>
    <httpModules>
        <add name="DomainServiceModule" type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHttpModule, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </httpModules>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"> 
      <assemblies><add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  <httpRuntime executionTimeout="36000"/>
  <!--<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="36000" />-->
</system.web>


<system.serviceModel>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="Sbinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="1500000000" maxBufferSize="1500000000">
        <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="1500000000" maxStringContentLength="1500000000" />
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>

    <webHttpBinding>
      <binding name="Ubinding" maxBufferSize="1500000000" maxBufferPoolSize="1500000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="1500000000" transferMode="Streamed">
        <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="1500000000" maxArrayLength="1500000000" maxBytesPerRead="1500000000" maxNameTableCharCount="1500000000" />
      </binding>
    </webHttpBinding>

  </bindings>

  <behaviors>
     <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="ClientUpload.Web.UploadService">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
            </behavior>

          <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
          </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>

    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="web">
        <webHttp />
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>


  <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="ClientUpload.Web.UploadService" name="ClientUpload.Web.Services.UploadService">
      <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Sbinding" contract="ClientUpload.Web.Services.IUploadService">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    </service>

    <service name="ClientUpload.Web.Services.RestService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
      <endpoint address="Rest" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ClientUpload.Web.Services.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="web" bindingConfiguration="Ubinding">
      </endpoint>
    </service>
  </services>             


</system.serviceModel>
```

-->
  -->

And Your Client Side ServiceReferences.ClientConfig file looks like

```
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>

    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IUploadService" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
                openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
                maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <security mode="None" />
            </binding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IUploadService1" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
                openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
                maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <security mode="None" />
            </binding>

        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

  <!--<client>
    <endpoint address="http://localhost/ClientUpload.Web_deploy/Services/UploadService.svc"
      binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IUploadService"
      contract="ServiceReference1.IUploadService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IUploadService" />
  </client>-->


  <client>
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:50503/Services/UploadService.svc"
      binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IUploadService1"
      contract="ServiceReference.ClientUpload.Web.Services.UploadService.IUploadService"
      name="BasicHttpBinding_IUploadService1" />
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:50503/Services/UploadService.svc"
      binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IUploadService"
      contract="ServiceReference1.IUploadService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IUploadService" />
  </client>

  <!--<client>
    <endpoint address="http://10.223.211.37:81/ClientUpload/Services/UploadService.svc"
      binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IUploadService"
      contract="ServiceReference1.IUploadService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IUploadService" />        
  </client>-->      

</system.serviceModel>
```