# Increase timeout of WCF service hosted on IIS server

Tags: sql-server, wcf, iis

I have a bunch of WCF services hosted on my server. One service is responsible for file transfer and times out when the user tries to upload large files.

I want to give the user an option to increase the timeout value for this particular service if he so desires. Currently, I'm using a 5 min timeout but this limit is reached when the files are large and the network is relatively slow on either side.

Is there a way to dynamically do so? Can I increase the timeout value for one service without affecting the others?

What I'd ideally like to achieve is to get the value from the user and set the clientTimeout and serverTimeout value accordingly. I have been able to set the client timeout but the server timeout is a limitation as of now. Any thoughts on this?

I have read these articles but could not figure out a way to increase the timeout for my service at runtime 
1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.executiontimeout.aspx

2. [WCF service timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9567999/wcf-service-timeout)

 3. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2008/03/10/why-changing-sendtimeout-does-not-help-for-hosted-wcf-services.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *configure* (throught XML or code) an endpoint with certain timeouts. This is set at servicehost startup and can't be changed while running.

Also no, a client can't set service timeouts, as this would make a denial-of-service-attack extremely easy.

You're best off by isolating the "file upload service" and configuring its endpoints accordingly.

Comment: Actually the user does not have direct access to the web services. I have an intermediate layer that does the web service calling. Depending on the user's input I would like to increase the timeout of 1 service, he would not be aware of that.

Comment: And the consumers of the service would be within the organization so DoS attacks are out of question here.
All that in place, you say that I cannot change the timeouts. If's thats the case then I'd have to think of another solution. Thanks!

Comment: I just said that to mention one of the reasons why that isn't possible by design. :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually the timeout problem happens on the client, not the host. In essence, the client sends a request but the host doesn't return a response in time and the (I think 2 minutes is default) timeout occurs.

You can increase or decrease the timeout setting at runtime for each service, with service defined as a unique URL:port/Class/Method, but to do so you have to define your service, binding, etc. at runtime, not using the standard web.config you often see.

On the host, you can set it like this:

```
Dim ServiceHostURI As New Uri(sURL)
Dim ServiceHost As New ServiceHost(GetType(YourClass), ServiceHostURI)
Dim sError As String = Nothing
Dim ServiceHostEndPoint As EndpointAddress = New EndpointAddress(ServiceHostURI)
Dim b As BasicHttpBinding

'binding timeoutsettings
  b = New BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None)
  'thirty minutes
  Dim specialTimeSpan = New TimeSpan(0, 30, 0)       
  b.CloseTimeout = specialTimeSpan
  b.ReceiveTimeout = specialTimeSpan
  b.SendTimeout = specialTimeSpan
  b.OpenTimeout = specialTimeSpan

'other binding settings
  b.TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered
  b.MaxReceivedMessageSize = Integer.MaxValue
  b.MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Text
  b.TextEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
  ServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(GetType(YourClass), binding, ServiceHostEndPoint.ToString)
  ServiceHost.Open()
```

On the client side, you can set the timeout this way:

```
    Dim hbe As New System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpTransportBindingElement()
    hbe.MaxBufferSize = Integer.MaxValue
    hbe.MaxBufferPoolSize = Integer.MaxValue
    hbe.MaxReceivedMessageSize = Integer.MaxValue

    binding.Elements.Add(hbe)
    binding.SendTimeout = New TimeSpan(0, 30, 0)
    binding.ReceiveTimeout = New TimeSpan(0, 30, 0)
```

The nice thing about this method is you can dynamically set the timeout in the code, but the change (obviously) only takes place on setup. You cannot change the timeout while the service is running. 
Hopefully, that's a help.