# Timeout in WCF Webservice call

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, mono

I have a C# application that makes calls to an IIS8-hosted web service using WCF. The responses to the calls can contain embedded base-64 encoded files, and can vary in size. I've encountered a situation recently where the web service call fails to complete on a call containing a somewhat large (~80 MB) file, with an exception  of System.TimeoutException, "the operation has timed-out". This exception always occurs exactly one minute after the call is made. The config file for the client program making the call has receiveTimeout, sendTimeout, openTimeout, and closeTimeout in the binding all set to values of 10 minutes. I have access to the web.config of the web service being called, which has the same values set for the binding there. The web.config also has compilation "debug" attribute set to "true", which should eliminate any possibility of an executeTimeout issue, if I understand that configuration correctly. What could be causing the time-out exception after one minute when the config is setup to wait for 10? The binding in use is as follows:

```
 <binding name="BasicHttpBinding"
              receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
              openTimeout="00:10:00" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
              maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
              maxBufferSize="2147483647">
 </binding>
```

The client is running under mono v4.0.1. This web service successfully fields hundreds of calls daily from several identically configured clients.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9567999/wcf-service-timeout

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not sure that link addresses the same issue, as that question regards setting a limit on the amount of time a web service spends executing. There are some other interesting links there, but most are referencing the timeout config settings above, which are already set on both client and server to 10 minutes, and my call raises the time-out exception after 1 minute.

Comment: You didn't mentioned your service session settings, so if you use transactions the timeout can be caused by system.transaction's default timeout. You might need to adjust the value - see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/madhuponduru/2005/12/16/how-to-change-system-transactions-timeout/